# php regex from java regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex (in PHP) to find

```
<ANYTHING_BUT_WHITSPACE>? OR ?<ANYTHING_BUT_WHITSPACE>
```

and replace the ? with a blank space. So, '?test test?' should become 'test test'. I have one working in java

```
"(?<=\\S)\\" + "?" + "|\\" + "?" + "(?=\\S)"
```

Any idea what it would be in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better pattern but almost the same:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\S)\?|\?(?=\S)/', '$1', '?test test?');
```

- Need delimiters in this case I used `/`
- Don't concatenate with `+` use `.` but not needed
- No need to double escape `\\`